# I have to get a family tatoo but in the future i might have to convert to islam?

Tags: halal-haram

So Im a female Maori and my boyfriend is muslim and in my family we have this tradition/cultural thing to get a a tattoo to represent us, our family and the things closest to us when we turn 18/21, but i know thats against his religion. i do not want to let my family down nor his but personally since i have never been a really big part of my original tribe or culture i would love to get this tattoo. i am planning for this relationship to last so i really dont want to mess things up by getting this tattoo bc i love him deeply and i love his family. i would really just love some advise or thoughts from other muslims or converters. please share every bit you think about this bc i really need the help 
  thank you xx

Answer (score 2):

Salam alaykum

Regarding this there are two matters that you should be considerate of:

1. You do not have to convert to islam to be with your boyfriend (although it would be amazing if you could learn about islam and fall in love with the religion as I did, eventually converting). If you do convert to islam, make sure that your reason is pure and that you do not do this out of love for your boyfriend but solely out of love for Allah and His prophet.
2. If you do get this tattoo then it does not prohibit you from later coming to insight and converting to islam. All your sins are forgiven upon conversion. However, you must discuss with your boyfriend as well and see if he would be fine with you having such a tattoo. I think it isn't very wise to show up with it suddenly...

Good luck!

Comment: i really appreciate this, its' help more than you think . I am trying to learn more about it when i have the time and i am slowly starting to love it. i have talked to him about it and he said that he doesn't really mind if i i get it but he said his parents might not accept it and thats what i'm worried about.